# How can I find out if a problem with the USB ports in my laptop is due to hardware or software?

Tags: usb, dmesg

A few days ago, the USB ports in my laptop stop working.  At first, I thought it might be due to a recent update of my OS (Ubuntu 14.04), so I began testing if something came up when connecting a wireless mouse while checking the `dmesg` output. Not even a message related to the USB port in the output, tough.

If there's no output for `dmesg` while testing some peripherals, I can conclude that the problem is due to hardware (a.k.a. broken USB ports), or there's some other way to prove that this can be a software problem?

Comment: Boot with an older LiveCD image, then plug something into the USB port while monitoring `dmesg`?  Also, you'll probably have more than one USB hub in your laptop - try all the ports.

Comment: also, do you see any output when running `lsusb`?

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Seems like the problem was due to a software update - Ubuntu updated some packages but failed in between, and somehow the laptop's power cord was disconnected and the laptop shutdown...  On the next reboot, the USB ports were dead - no response and no messages from `dmesg`.  However, I updated the system and then issue a normal reboot, and the next time I log in the USB ports were working as usual :)  I guess the question is *could the failed update have caused this problem?*.  And if it happens again, *is there a way to force the USB ports to "restart"?*